# Uploading files using Qt QNetworkRequest

Tags: qt, file-upload, qnetworkaccessmanager

I've been having some issues trying to upload files to a server using QNetworkRequest. I've been using this link (http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11361) mostly as a template, but am still getting POST errors (203 to be specific). Here is what I have so far.

```
void MainWindow::processFile(){

    QByteArray postData;
    //Look below for buildUploadString() function
    postData = mReport->buildUploadString();

    QUrl mResultsURL = QUrl("http://" + VariableManager::getInstance()->getServerIP() +  "/uploadFile.php");
    QNetworkAccessManager* mNetworkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);


    QString bound="margin"; //name of the boundary

    QNetworkRequest request(mResultsURL); //our server with php-script
    request.setRawHeader(QString("Content-Type").toAscii(),QString("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + bound).toAscii());
    request.setRawHeader(QString("Content-Length").toAscii(), QString::number(postData.length()).toAscii());


    connect(mNetworkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(printScriptReply(QNetworkReply*))); //This slot is used to debug the output of the server script
    mNetworkManager->post(request,postData);
}


QByteArray ReportParser::buildUploadString()
{
    QString path = VariableManager::getInstance()->getReportDirectory();
    path.append("\\\\");
    path.append(getReportFileName());


    QString bound="margin";
    QByteArray data(QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toAscii());
    data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"action\"\r\n\r\n");
    data.append("uploadFile.php\r\n");   
    data.append(QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toAscii());   
    data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded\"; filename=\"");
    data.append(getReportFileName());
    data.append("\"\r\n");  
    data.append("Content-Type: text/xml\r\n\r\n"); //data type

    QFile file(path);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
            qDebug() << "QFile Error: File not found!";
            return data;
        } else { qDebug() << "File found, proceed as planned"; }

    data.append(file.readAll());           
    data.append("\r\n");
    data.append("--" + bound + "--\r\n");  //closing boundary according to rfc 1867


    file.close();

    return data;
}
```

Here is the script on the server to process the file:

```
<?php

       $uploaded_type = $_FILES['uploaded']['type'];

    $target = "/var/www/webpage/results/";
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;
    $ok=1;

    echo "target: ";
    echo $target;

    //This is our limit file type condition
    if ($uploaded_type =="text/xml"){
            echo "We have an xml file!\r\n";
    }

    //Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error
    //If everything is ok we try to upload it
    if ($ok==0){

            echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded";

    } else {

            echo "Looking good!";

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)){
                    echo "The file successfully ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
            } else {
                    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
            }
    }
?>
```

I know that the script works, as it will handle the file properly when using a basic HTML form. However, the Qt side of things keeps returning POST errors.

Comment: This can be marked as solved. Apparently the problem was not with my code, but with the network connection dropping packets. The above code actually works for the task at hand, so if anyone stumbles upon this via Google, this will work.

Comment: Then I'ld suggest you either put a [SOLVED] in the question's title or else write an answer to it (given SO's traditions, better do the second).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was dropped packets on the network. The above code actually works.