# QHttpMultiPart upload multiple files

Tags: php, c++, qt

I'm attempting to upload (POST) multiple files to a web-server through my application. The PHP end works, as I have used cURL to upload, but I wanted to do the same thing through Qt.

I've looked at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235107/qhttpmultipart-post-files-to-php-script), but I'm not sure how to transform it to upload multiple files.

```cpp
QUrl url(connServer + "/api.php");
QNetworkRequest request(url);

QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

QString preview_path  = "C:/preview.jpg";
QHttpPart previewPathPart;
previewPathPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"preview_path\""));
previewPathPart.setBody(preview_path.toLatin1()); /* <-------------- I'm stumped here */
multiPart->append(previewPathPart);

for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    qDebug(list[i].toStdString().c_str());
    continue;

    QString filename = list[i];

    QHttpPart previewFilePart;
    previewFilePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,    QVariant("image/jpeg"));
    previewFilePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"preview_file\"; filename=\""+ filename + "\""));
    QFile *file = new QFile(preview_path);

    file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    previewFilePart.setBodyDevice(file);
    file->setParent(multiPart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multiPart

    multiPart->append(previewFilePart);
}

QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkReply* reply = networkManager->post(request, multiPart);
multiPart->setParent(reply); // delete the multiPart with the reply

connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT  (uploadReply()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT  (uploadError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT  (uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
```

What parts of the QHttpMultiPart should be setup once, and what parts are setup multiple times for each of the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code above is close, but I just needed to figure out what code specified the one time variables, and what code specified the files. This code works to upload multiple files. However... it can only upload 20 files at a time. Not sure if that is a limit of Qt or something else. My equivalent Perl/cURL program can upload hundreds of files to the same PHP page without problem.

```cpp
QUrl url(connServer + "/api.php");
QNetworkRequest request(url);

QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

QHttpPart loginPart;
/* username */
loginPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"u\""));
loginPart.setBody(connUsername.toLatin1());
multiPart->append(loginPart);
/* password */
loginPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"p\""));
loginPart.setBody(connPassword.toLatin1());
multiPart->append(loginPart);
/* action */
loginPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"action\""));
loginPart.setBody("UploadDICOM");
multiPart->append(loginPart);

/* loop through the list of files */
ui->progUpload->setRange(0,100);
for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    qDebug("UploadFileList [%d] [%s]", i, list[i].toStdString().c_str());
    QFile *file = new QFile(list[i]);
    QHttpPart filePart;
    /* important that the files[] variable have the brackets, for PHP to interpret correctly */
    filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"files[]\"; filename=\""+ file->fileName() + "\""));

    file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    filePart.setBodyDevice(file);
    file->setParent(multiPart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multiPart
    multiPart->append(filePart);
}

QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkReply* reply = networkManager->post(request, multiPart);
multiPart->setParent(reply); // delete the multiPart with the reply
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onGetReply()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT  (uploadError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT  (uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
```